# Are there any news about a Chinese anime movie called "Kuiyu Chouyuan" since its trailer?

Tags: kuiyu-chouyuan

I have been looking for a Chinese anime called *Kuiyu Chouyuan*, but couldn't find it. Here are the 2 trailers:

- [First trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLF4dAqyyBY&t=64s) (reposted in 2017), the same as [this video with Chinese title](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJGF0MGGc8U&t=94s) (posted in 2014)
- [Second trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhZan6sDk08) (reposted in 2017)

Are there any news about the anime since the trailer was posted? Are there any manga/other adaptation?

Comment: Looks like the question is not really about ID request, but more about the progress of the (past, abandoned) anime project which has an answer already: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/a827sz/looking_for_this_movie_suichenglixin_kuiyu/), [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1715864), [Novel Updates](https://forum.novelupdates.com/threads/kuiyu-chouyuan-demon-curse-xianxia-anime.28278/). I feel this is on-topic, but this is just my personal view.